# Numeric solution such that NIntegrate becomes zero

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to find the numeric solution such that a numeric integral becomes zero. Unfortunately, Mathematica does not seem to like vanishing integrals. As the solution is approached, NIntegrated throws errors and becomes very slow. Here a minimal example:

```
g[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(x - 1) (x - a) (x + 1), {x, -1, 1}]
n = 0;
(* Solution is a=0. As it is approached, NIntegrate throws errors. *)
FindRoot[g[a] == 0, {{a, 0.8}}, EvaluationMonitor :> (n++; Print[{n, a, g[a]}])]
```

How can I make this work smoothly?

Comment: If you use `NIntegrate`'s `Method->"LocalAdaptive"` then it doesn't complain.

Comment: Thank you all. This solves the toy problem. Fingers crossed that it works for the actual problem.

Comment: You can also just ignore the problem by wrapping NIntegrate in Quiet. Like it's nice to know how NIntegrate is feeling but sometimes it needs to complain less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a design choice that the default `AccuracyGoal` in `NIntegrate` is `Infinity`. That means the integral must be approximated to exactly zero or you'll get messages. You probably don't want the `AccuracyGoal` to be less than machine epsilon times the maximum of the integrand. And if the integrand has more numerical error for whatever reason, you might want it a little bigger. Of course, the bigger it is, the greater the error that will be tolerated.

The integrand at hand, being a low-degree polynomial, is integrated exactly, less whatever round-off error there is in the floating-point evaluations. It is because of this that the error estimate when using arbitrary precision can be expected to be equal to zero on this example. But, for instance, `NIntegrate[(x - 1)  (x - a) (x + 1) BesselJ[2, Abs[10 x]], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]` gives some errors because truncation error is not zero in the integration method. If the integral is close to zero, the final error is not zero. and `AccuracyGoal` is too large, then `NIntegrate` complains.

For instance, this works on the toy example (as well as the one with the `BesselJ` factor in the previous paragraph):

```
g[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(x - 1)  (x - a) (x + 1), {x, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 16]
n = 0;
FindRoot[g[a] == 0, {{a, 0.8}}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> (n++; Print[{n, a, g[a]}])]
```

Answer (score 6):

Without `Method`- option (see flinty's helpful comment) try `NMinimize`

```
g[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(x - 1) (x - a) (x + 1), {x, -1, 1} ]
NMinimize[g[a]^2, a] (*{5.21954*10^-30, {a -> 1.71584*10^-15}}*)
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow at work the Method option with the actual problem. But using Minimize, I really wonder why it works. At the solution, the numerical integral has exactly the same problem.

Comment: @RainerGlüge Numerical solver of `NMinimize` is very robust and often works in cases where Findroot fails

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

For this problem, there is no reason to use `NIntegrate`

```
g[a_] = Integrate[(x - 1)  (x - a)  (x + 1), {x, -1, 1}]


(* (4 a)/3 *)

Solve[g[a] == 0, a]

(* {{a -> 0}} *)
```

However, if you must use `NIntegrate`, don't use machine precision.

```
Clear[g]

g[av_?NumericQ, wp_ : 15] := Module[{a = Rationalize[av, 0]},
  NIntegrate[(x - 1)  (x - a)  (x + 1), {x, -1, 1},
   WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

NSolve[g[a] == 0, a]

(* NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{a -> 0.}} *)
```

Comment: I am aware that this problem does not need NIntegrate. It is just for illustration. The actual problem involves 2 equations and several nested numerical integrations.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to go through similar problem, summarizing what had to be done in case it's useful:

- `FindRoot`'s implementation of Newton's method didn't work for me, had to impement Newton's method myself in `findRoot`
- default `NIntegrate` was too noisy to for numeric inversion, unless I used `Method->"LocalAdaptive"`
- default `NIntegrate` for computing derivate was too noisy unless I used `Method -> "PrincipalValue"`, and manually excluded points where function was infinite

```
(* Find root between a0 and b0 using initial guess 0 for function f and derivative df *)
findRoot[c0_, a0_, b0_, f_, df_] := 
  Module[{a, b, c, x, y, dy, maxIters, stopCriterion},
   c = c0;
   a = a0;
   b = b0;
   x = c;
   maxIters = 100;
   stopCriterion = 10^-6;
   For[i = 1, i <= maxIters, i += 1,
    y = f[x];
     If[Abs[y] < stopCriterion, Break[]];
     dy = df[x];
     x = x - y/dy; (* replace with (dy+eps) for ill-conditoned *);
    (* check if x got out of interval *);
    Which[
     x < a, x = (a + b)/2; b = c,
     x > b, x = (a + b)/2; a = c,
     True,
     _
     ];
    c = x;
    ];
   c
   ];

adaptiveIntegrate[expr_] := 
  NIntegrate[expr, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
pvalueIntegrate[expr_, exclusion_] := 
  NIntegrate[expr, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
   Exclusions -> {exclusion}, MinRecursion -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 20];
expr[n_, a_, x_] = (
  2^(-n/2) E^(-((n x)/2)) (1/n)^(-n/2) x^(-1 + n/2) Log[(1 - a x)^2])/
  Gamma[n/2];
exprD[n_, a_, x_] = D[expr[n, a, x], a];
meanLog[n_, a_?NumericQ] := adaptiveIntegrate[expr[n, a, x]];
meanLogD[n_, a_?NumericQ] := 
  pvalueIntegrate[exprD[n, a, x], 1 - a x == 0];
invert[n_?NumericQ] := 
  findRoot[2.5, 2, 3, meanLog[n, #] &, meanLogD[n, #] &];
Plot[invert[n], {n, 0.6, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```